# Loading model of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem loading a model, i have code like this

```
function __construct() {
    $this->load->model("admin_model");
    parent::__construct();
}



function login() {

  $log = $this->admin_model->login($username, $pass);

}
```

if i use the code above, i get this error
    A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: admin_controller::$admin_model

Filename: controllers/admin_controller.php

Line Number: 43


Fatal error: Call to a member function admin_login() on a non-object in   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\admin_controller.php on line 43
```

Comment: You can also autoload models in the config file

Comment: this problem should have been resolved by first calling `parent::__construct()` then loading model

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on top of your `function parent::__construct();`